# Collection of Nonempty Subsets of $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ a Class or Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

In ZFC, is the collection $\mathcal{N}$ of nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ a class or set? Please correct me if I am wrong, but so far as I understand the notion of class, a class is a collection of objects which satisfy a certain property $P$. In this example, let $P$ be the property that $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$. Take $N=\{S|PS \}$. Then is $N$ not just our collection $\mathcal{N}$, and is $N$ not a class?

Comment: ZFC has the power set axiom.

Comment: Okay, so $\mathcal{N}$ is a set, but is is also a class?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284709/zfc-with-class-terms-is-any-set-also-a-class (in short: every set is a class, classes which are not sets are called proper classes.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you! +1

Comment: I guess we can close this as a duplicate, then.